# Close other div's when using slidetoggel

Tags: slidetoggle

I use this code below on my site to open some div's. It works almost perfectly. But when i open a second div I want the other div to close. How can i do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#reveal1').hide();
jQuery('.rv_button1').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#reveal1").slideToggle();
jQuery('.rv_button1').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#reveal2').hide();
jQuery('.rv_button2').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#reveal2").slideToggle();
jQuery('.rv_button2').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#reveal3').hide();
jQuery('.rv_button3').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#reveal3").slideToggle();
jQuery('.rv_button3').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});

</script>
```